# Calling function with unknown number of parameters

Tags: python, args

I am trying to create a set of functions in python that will all do a similar operation on a set of inputs. All of the functions have one input parameter fixed and half of them also need a second parameter. For the sake of simplicity, below is a toy example with only two functions.

Now, I want, in my script, to run the appropriate function, depending on what the user input as a number. Here, the user is the random function (so the minimum example works). What I want to do is something like this:

```
def function_1(*args):
    return args[0]

def function_2(*args):
    return args[0] * args[1]

x = 10
y = 20
i = random.randint(1,2)
f = function_1 if i==1 else function_2
return_value = f(x,y)
```

And it works, but it seems messy to me. I would rather have `function_1` defined as

```
def function_1(x):
    return x
```

Another way would be to define

```
def function_1(x,y):
    return x
```

But that leaves me with a dangling `y` parameter.

but that will not work as easily. Is my way the "proper" way of solving my problem or does there exist a better way?

Comment: are the functions totally different from each other?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're attempting to accomplish that makes `*args` "messy". `function_1` only requires one parameter?

Comment: @Elizion Yes, the function requires only one parameter, that's why I think `*args` is weird to use here.

Comment: @YuriMalheiros The functions do completely different things. This is because I have a three step process, and the functions only encode the third part. I have a function that 1) performs the first 2 steps, 2) finds the function that will perform the last step and 3) executes the third step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of approaches here, all of them adding more boiler-plate code.

There is also this [PEP](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0443/) which may be interesting to you.

But 'pythonic' way of doing it is not as elegant as usual function overloading due to the fact that functions are just class attributes.

So you can either go with function like that:

`def foo(*args):`

and then count how many `args` you've got which will be very broad but very flexible as well.

another approach is the default arguments:

`def foo(first, second=None, third=None)`

less flexible but easier to predict, and then lastly you can also use:

`def foo(anything)`

and detect the type of `anything` in your function acting accordingly.

Your monkey-patching example can work too, but it becomes more complex if you use it with class methods, and does make introspection tricky.

EDIT: Also, for your case you may want to keep the functions separate and write single 'dispatcher' function that will call appropriate function for you depending on the arguments, which is probably best solution considering above.

EDIT2: base on your comments I believe that following approach may work for you

```
def weigh_dispatcher(*args, **kwargs):
    #decide which function to call base on args
    if 'somethingspecial' in kwargs:
        return weight2(*args, **kwargs)


def weight_prep(arg):
    #common part here

def weight1(arg1, arg2):
    weitht_prep(arg1)
    #rest of the func

def weight2(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    weitht_prep(arg1)
    #rest of the func
```

alternatively you can move the common part into the dispatcher

Answer (score 2):

You may also have a function with optional second argument:

```
def function_1(x, y = None):
  if y != None:
    return x + y
  else:
    return x
```

Here's the sample run:

```
>>> function_1(3)
3
>>> function_1(3, 4)
7
```

Or even optional multiple arguments! Check this out:

```
def function_2(x, *args):
  return x + sum(args)
```

And the sample run:

```
>>> function_2(3)
3
>>> function_2(3, 4)
7
>>> function_2(3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
25
```

You may here refer to `args` as to list:

```
def function_3(x, *args):
  if len(args) < 1:
    return x
  else:
    return x + sum(args)
```

And the sample run:

```
>>> function_3(1,2,3,4,5)
15
```

Comment: The functions are more different than in the toy example and much longer, so I don't want to separate the cases into huge if statements that are very hard to read...

Comment: @5xum so maybe you'd better refactor your functions? ;) Alternatively, you may extract the common part for all those functions (except some rare cases) and write a single one. Otherwise, I assume that's better to use a few functions

Comment: I did extract the common part of the functions, that's how I got to the point where I am. Basically, I have one function that performs some sort of weighing. And it can perform it in three different ways, all of them have the same first step and different second steps. I want to perform the first step, then call the appropriate function for the second step.

Comment: @5xum I believe your situation is simple enought, but I suggest you then using some design patterns like `chain of responsibility` (I am not good at it right now, but I believe that is what gonna work for you)